# Nginx Extract Top Directory Name From Request URI

Tags: nginx, web-server, rewrite, regex

I am in the need of being able to use top directory from the `$request_uri`, for example:

`/dir/sub/slug` -> `/dir`

I read the answer of this question:
[How to extract Only the file name from the request uri](https://serverfault.com/questions/381545/how-to-extract-only-the-file-name-from-the-request-uri)

```
# Gets the basename of the original request
map $request_uri $request_basename {
    ~/(?<captured_request_basename>[^/?]*)(?:\?|$) $captured_request_basename;
}

# Gets the basename of the current uri
map $uri $basename {
    ~/(?<captured_basename>[^/]*)$ $captured_basename;
}
```

And it seems to be close with what I need, how does that works? is it possible to be modified to get the top directory instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that something like this should do the trick.

In my sample, to test what was returned, i added the variable `$topdir` into the Header.

```
map $request_uri $topdir {
   ~(?<captured_topdir>^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[/]) $captured_topdir;
}

server {
  listen  80;
  root /var/www;
  index  index.html;

  location / {
    add_header X-Top-Dir $topdir;
  }
}
```

- `http://mydomain.com/dir/sub/slug/page.html` should return `/dir/`
- `http://mydomain.com` or `http://mydomain.com/page.html` should return nothing

Comment: Many thanks! This Works! Wish I could up vote a hundred times! :) 2 little questions, is that possible to omit the last `/`? or is it possible to escape nginx variable in a string? e.g: `{$topdir}/sub/index.php`?

Comment: Late answer: Yes, to omit the last slash you just have to move the bracket a bit forward like: ~(?<captured_topdir>^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]